# OTP Verification in Node

Tags: node.js, express, sms, forgot-password

What could be the standard practice in verifying OTP received from the client is correct?
Especially in Node environment without using any extra space?

Comment: You are looking for the TOTP standard. https://www.npmjs.com/package/totp-generator

Comment: Yup but my question is different. I am talking about SMS OTPs. I don't want to store the otp generated for the client in my db. But have to verify the client sent otp in node. Is there any standard process for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SMS (which is generally considered one of the weaker forms of MFA, and is not recommended), then the simplest way is to generate an OTP, store it in a database (or similar) against the user's account, and then verify against the one they provide. You should also store a timestamp with it, so that OTPs are only valid for a specific length of time.